# Unable to ignore the exception in Catch Exception Strategy

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

The below is the flow which I am trying to ignore the exception..

```xml
<flow name="demoFlow1" doc:name="demoFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:5050/demo" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <set-payload value="#['sucess']" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <catch-exception-strategy when="#[!exception.causedBy(org.mule.api.registry.ResolverException)]" doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
        <logger message="Exception in flow" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </catch-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

I am getting the below error

```java
org.mule.api.construct.FlowConstructInvalidException: **Flow exception listener contains and exception strategy that doesn't handle all request, Perhaps there's an exception strategy with a when attribute set but it's not part of a catch exception strategy**
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.validateConstruct(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:286)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline.validateConstruct(AbstractPipeline.java:227)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$1.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:108)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$1.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:103)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:138)
    at org.mule.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager.fireInitialisePhase(FlowConstructLifecycleManager.java:78)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.initialise(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:102)
```

Could you please help me out on this in mule 3.4.2 version?

Answer (score 1):

Use a choice exception instead, then put that catch exception inside.

```
<flow name="demoFlow1" doc:name="demoFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:5050/demo" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <set-payload value="#['sucess']" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <choice-exception-strategy doc:name="Choice Exception Strategy">
         <catch-exception-strategy when="#[!exception.causedBy(org.mule.api.registry.ResolverException)]" doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
             <logger message="Exception in flow" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
         </catch-exception-strategy>
    </choice-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

Not sure if you would need a generic catch exception, but the above works at 3.6. If in case, do this below (with generic catch exception - no 'when' attribute)

```
<flow name="demoFlow1" doc:name="demoFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:5050/demo" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <set-payload value="#['sucess']" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <choice-exception-strategy doc:name="Choice Exception Strategy">
         <catch-exception-strategy when="#[!exception.causedBy(org.mule.api.registry.ResolverException)]" doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
             <logger message="Exception in flow" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
         </catch-exception-strategy>
         <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
             <logger message="Exception in flow" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
         </catch-exception-strategy>
    </choice-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

Comment: Still It is not working I tried with above options in 3.4.2 . is there any other option to do?

Comment: I just tried on 3.4.2. Works fine with me.. What error are you getting?

Comment: we are not getting any compile time error.. It is showing the error(whatever the error we have mentioned in the 'when' condition) if your ignoring still in the logs. Ideally It should ignore the error right. Correct me if am wrong !!!

Comment: I'm afraid not. The logs are still be printed whether the exception is caught or not.. I agree with you though that Mule should not print it, same as what Java does on try-catch.

Comment: Is it possible to ignore the stack trace as well in 3.4.2?

Comment: No, I don't think you can.. Maybe you can explore via log4j.properties instead.

Comment: How it is working 3.6. is it ignoring stack trace as well ?

Comment: I'm not sure if we are still on the same page. Basically same thing happens for 3.4.2 and 3.6.2 to me. Both will write the stack trace on log whether the exception is caught or not...  Is this still your error "org.mule.api.construct.FlowConstructInvalidException: **Flow exception listener contains and exception strategy that doesn't handle all request, Perhaps there's an exception strategy with a when attribute set but it's not part of a catch exception strategy**"?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think it's possible to avoid the exception from being logged even though the Catch Exception Strategy is handling it. I created this [JIRA](https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6575) in the ESB a while ago and it seems it's still open.

Answer (score 0):

Pbris this Exception based Expression (when Condition)

`when="#[!exception.causedBy(org.mule.api.registry.ResolverException)]`

it  has to be used only in Choice exception Strategy here where you have been writing catch-exception-strategy

`<catch-exception-strategy when="#[!exception.causedBy(org.mule.api.registry.ResolverException)]" doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
        <logger message="Exception in flow" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</catch-exception-strategy>`

This block of code won't work until remove the when condition
same thing would work in choice exception strategy with out removing the when condition

Take the reference from mule esb  documentation

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. Use catch exception inside Choice exception, this will work